# How to join range of ranges?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

How to join range of ranges?

```
auto points() const
    {
        auto ranges = children() | std::views::transform([](auto child) { return child->points(); });
        return std::views::join(ranges);
    }
```

Can`t use points at

```
for(auto& pt: points())
```

Error no operator "!=" matches these operands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on what exactly `children()` and `child::points()` return.

If `children()` returns a container by value, then you are creating an adaptor (via piping with `|`) that is *dangling* - its iterators cannot be dereferenced.

In addition, `child::points()` must return a [`view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view). Returning a container won't work.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

struct child {
    std::vector<int> points_{1, 2, 3};

    const auto& points() const {
        return points_;
    }
};

struct element {
    std::vector<child> children_{{}, {}};

    const auto& children() const {
        return children_;
    }

    auto points() const {
        auto ranges = children() | std::views::transform([](auto& child) {
            return std::views::all(child.points());
        });
        return std::views::join(ranges);
    }

};

int main() {
    auto e = element();
    for (auto x : e.points()) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

Notice how accessors (`child::points()` and `element::children()`) return by `const&`.

Comment: join() works perfect. It can join range of ranges